# UIGestureRecognizer works outside of UIView borders instead of inside

Tags: ios, swift, popup, uikit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I've implemented a popup notification in my app to show user the data was being updated successfully or not.

This popup is just a UIView instantiated from .xib. Here is screenshot of elements hierarchy in xib file: [CLICK](https://cln.sh/te8JhM)

Also I wanted the ability to swipe out the popup if user don't want to see a full time it shows itself on the screen. To do that I have implemented a UIGestureRecognizer:

```
    private func configureTapGesture() {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: {$0.isKeyWindow}) else { return }
    let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
    swipe.direction = .up
    window.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
}

@objc private func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.direction == .up {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            self.popupView.center.y -= 50
        } completion: { _ in
            self.popupView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        self.isRemovedByTap = true
    }
}
```

When I run the app it works only if I swipe out anywhere but not inside the popupView. Please check for the GIF: [CLICK](https://cln.sh/sNm5RN)

If I replace a target from `self` (Popup class) to `popupView` (UIVisualEffectView, which is a rounded rectangle you see on GIF), then I receive an error `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Here is a my full custom Popup class where I initialize the view, configure, animate and show it:

```
import UIKit

  class PopupView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var popupView: UIVisualEffectView!
@IBOutlet weak var symbol: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

private var isRemovedByTap = false

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    configure()
}

private func configure() {
    if let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PopupView", owner: self) {
        guard let view = views.first as? UIView else { return }
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
    }
}

private func configurePopup() {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: {$0.isKeyWindow}) else { return }
    popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    popupView.clipsToBounds = true
    popupView.center.x = window.frame.midX
    popupView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    window.addSubview(popupView)
}

private func animatePopup() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
        self.popupView.center.y += 34
    } completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 10.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            self.popupView.center.y -= 50
        } completion: { _ in
            if !self.isRemovedByTap {
                self.popupView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}

private func configureTapGesture() {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: {$0.isKeyWindow}) else { return }
    let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
    swipe.direction = .up
    window.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
}

@objc private func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.direction == .up {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            self.popupView.center.y -= 50
        } completion: { _ in
            self.popupView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        self.isRemovedByTap = true
    }
}

func showPopup(title: String, message: String, symbol: UIImage) {
    titleLabel.text = title
    descriptionLabel.text = message
    self.symbol.image = symbol
    
    configurePopup()
    animatePopup()
    configureTapGesture()
}
}
```

What should I change to be able to swipe out only when inside the popupView rounded rectangle?

Comment: First, is there a reason you are adding the view to the `window` instead of the current view? Second, do you want the user to be able to swipe up *anywhere*? or *only inside* the view?

Comment: Hi @DonMag. 1)yes, reason is that I want it to be shown on any active vc. I can switch to another vc and want the popup to be shown till it’s time is over 2) only inside the popupView

Comment: Since you have added gesture to window and not to popup view its working only when you swipe on window, I will suggest you to add gesture to pop up view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple issues - without seeing your xib view hierarchy, I can't test this completely, but it should get you on your way.

You are adding the swipe gesture to the *window* ...

The reason you can't swipe *inside* the popup view is because the popup view captures the touch gestures. If you set `.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` you should be able to swipe inside the view.

If you want to swipe ***only*** inside the view, check the swipe location and see if the view contains that point.

Along these lines:

```
@objc private func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    // may need to convert touch and frame
    let loc = sender.location(in: self)
    let r = popupView.frame
    if sender.direction == .up, r.contains(loc) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            self.popupView.center.y -= 50
        } completion: { _ in
            self.popupView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        self.isRemovedByTap = true
    }
}
```

You'll need to debug the frame and gesture coordinates to make sure you're checking the correct area.

---

**Edit**

To check if the swipe is inside the popupView frame, we have to do a couple things...

Add a new property -- I'll call it `yAdjustment` -- and then in your `animatePopup()` func, set that to the popupView's y origin:

```
var yAdjustment: CGFloat = 0

private func animatePopup() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
        self.popupView.center.y += 34
        // save the top of the popupView frame
        self.yAdjustment = self.popupView.frame.origin.y
    } completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 10.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            self.popupView.center.y -= 50
        } completion: { _ in
            if !self.isRemovedByTap {
                self.popupView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then, change your swipe region testing to this:

```
@objc private func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    // get location of swipe
    var loc = sender.location(in: popupView)

    // adjust the touch y
    loc.y -= (yAdjustment - popupView.frame.origin.y)

    // get the view bounds
    let r = popupView.bounds
    
    // only do this if
    //  swipe direct is up
    //  AND
    //  swipe location is inside popupView
    if sender.direction == .up, r.contains(loc) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            self.popupView.center.y -= 50
        } completion: { _ in
            self.popupView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        self.isRemovedByTap = true
    }
    
}
```

The reason we have to "correct" the frame...

When you write that chained animation block, this line:

```
self.popupView.center.y -= 50
```

is executed **immediately** -- the *animation* is simply delayed (by 10-seconds, in this case).

Normally, we would get the touch location ***in the view's frame*** and see if it is contained in the bounds.

In this case, though, because the view's frame has already been changed - even though we don't *see it yet* - we have to compensate for the new location.

Comment: Thank you. Please take a look at my view hierarchy. Maybe you can add something after it: https://cln.sh/te8JhM

Comment: @artexhibit - right-click on your xib and select `Open As -> Source Code` ... then copy/paste that somewhere so I can work with the same thing you're using (pastebin or gist.github)

Comment: got it. here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/artexhibit/648b6009f8a570ff7801dcefd69a4a15 Also: 1) turn off .isUserInteractionEnabled and now I am able to swipe up outside and inside the popupView. 2) loc constant prints only (0,0). Seems it's not working. r constant prints its frame coordinate normally: https://cln.sh/aTxw5p

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, DonMag! Here is how I managed to achieve the swipe off in popupView borders: https://gist.github.com/artexhibit/9a672dfa3e7ed9f35ef92773a6d078bf

Comment: @artexhibit - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Big thank you! your implementation is much more better! Will stick to yours. Also can you check mine (second gist)? What do you think of how I have done it though window?

Comment: @artexhibit - hmmm... as far as I can tell with your second gist, the swipe is still active over the entire screen, not just inside the popup view?

Comment: Nope, swipe works only inside borders of popupView. Swipe outside of it don’t work. The code looks irrational, but works…

Comment: @artexhibit -- your 2nd gist code is testing a "popup view sized rectangle" inside the entire window... if you try to swipe up from *within* the popup view, but towards the right-side of it, `window.frame.contains(popupFrame)` will fail, because `popupFrame` extends off the right-side of the window. Also, if you swipe up from near the *bottom* of the screen, but vertically in-line with the left-half of the popupView, `window.frame.contains(popupFrame)` will return `true` and you can swipe it off the screen.

Comment: No need in further explanations, I got it! Thank you, really appreciate!

Comment: @artexhibit - one last thing to look at: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/3bad784b4c0d09dd1bbe6bcb19e10e37 ... test view controller, slightly modified xib, new `PopupView` class. Takes advantage of auto-layout... uses Pan instead of Swipe to make it more responsive... uses Gesture on self instead of on full window -- so no more hoops to find out if the touch is inside the view... compliant with Scenes.

Comment: DonMag, thank you so much! Never thought someone can be so helpful! I’ll dig into it and make my code better

Answer (score 0):

```
private func configureTapGesture() {
     guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: {$0.isKeyWindow}) else { return }
     let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
     swipe.direction = .up
     window.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

    // you also must add this and test it
    self.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Tested and with that change I can't swipe up even when do it outside the popupVIew

Comment: I thinks that you must have two swipe gestures, one for popupview, other one for window.

Comment: But the thing is I don't need a swipe up when do it outside the popupView, only when I do it inside borders of popupView. But when I change target from self to popupView it throws an error "unrecognized selector sent to instance"